Go idiomatic way to verify that a directory is not a git submodule
I can check if the indicated path is a git repository using the go-git PlainOpen:
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5"
)

func errAndExit(err error) {
    fmt.Printf("\n%v\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

func main() {
    path := os.Args[1]
    fmt.Println("given path =", path)
    pathInfo, err := os.Stat(path)
    if err != nil {
        errAndExit(err)
    }
    if !pathInfo.IsDir() {
        errAndExit(
            fmt.Errorf(
                "‘%s’ is not a directory",
                pathInfo.Name(),
            ),
        )
    }
    rep, err := git.PlainOpen(path)
    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, git.ErrRepositoryNotExists) {
            errAndExit(
                fmt.Errorf(
                    "we should be prepared for: %w",
                    err,
                ),
            )
        }
        errAndExit(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n%#v\n", rep)
}

Is there a nice method for pure Go to check that the path given points to a git repository that is not a submodule?
Below is a workaround that I would prefer to avoid.
In git CLI, all I need to do is check the result of the git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree command:
package gitcli

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

const (
    newLine             = "\n"
    pathToGitExecutable = "/usr/bin/git"
)

func callRevParse(dPAth, rpCommand string) (string, error) {
    gitRevParse := exec.Command(
        pathToGitExecutable,
        "rev-parse",
        rpCommand,
    )
    gitRevParse.Dir = dPAth
    var out bytes.Buffer
    gitRevParse.Stdout = &out
    err := gitRevParse.Run()
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf(
            "failed to invoke `git rev-parse %s` command in ‘%s’ path: %w",
            rpCommand,
            dPath,
            err,
        )
    }
    return out.String(), err
}

func verifyIsNotSubmodule(dPath string) error {
    rpSSWT, err := callRevParse(dPath, "--show-superproject-working-tree")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(strings.Trim(rpSSWT, newLine)) > 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf(
            "‘%s’ is a git submodule",
            dPath,
        )
    }
    return nil
}

I am aware of the existence of go-git-cmd-wrapper, but it was quicker to be as above

I didn't find a way to do that in https://github.com/go-git/go-git so
maybe it would be a good opportunity for you to contribute to this
open source project and add it?

(A glib response, but anyway…) it appears that the only way forward is to see how git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree is implemented (Git is F/OSS, after all) and recreate that in Go. Git is plain C, and all it does in the end is calling out to libc which exposes basically the same set of operation on files the Go's os package does.

At the current master's tip, the command basically relies on parsing the output of the call to git --literal-pathspecs -C .. ls-files -z --stage --full-name --, so if go-git provides an equivalent to that call, that'd be 80% of the implementation.

@kostix: one also needs to able to tell the difference between nested git repositories and submodules

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk, yeah, the native Git code of course makes this distinction.

rev-parse isn't yet supported in
go-git
but we could roll our own implementation based on this
comment:
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"
        "path/filepath"
        stdpath "path/filepath"
)

func isSubmodule(path string) (bool, error) {
        // normalize the path
        path, err := filepath.Abs(path)
        if err != nil {
                return false, err
        }

        for {
                fi, err := os.Stat(stdpath.Join(path, ".git"))
                if err == nil {
                        if !fi.IsDir() {
                                return true, nil
                        }
                        return false, nil
                }
                if !os.IsNotExist(err) {
                        // unknown error
                        return false, err
                }

                // detect bare repo
                ok, err := isGitDir(path)
                if err != nil {
                        return false, err
                }
                if ok {
                        return true, nil
                }

                if parent := filepath.Dir(path); parent == path {
                        return false, fmt.Errorf(".git not found")
                } else {
                        path = parent
                }
        }
}

func isGitDir(path string) (bool, error) {
        markers := []string{"HEAD", "objects", "refs"}

        for _, marker := range markers {
                _, err := os.Stat(stdpath.Join(path, marker))
                if err == nil {
                        continue
                }
                if !os.IsNotExist(err) {
                        // unknown error
                        return false, err
                } else {
                        return false, nil
                }
        }

        return true, nil
}

func main() {
        if s, err := isSubmodule(os.Args[1]); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        } else {
                log.Println("Is submodule:", s)
        }
}

To be 100% safe we could also try parsing contents of .git file in
submodules. The gitdir:  prefix is defined in
go-git
but not exported. Maybe it would actually be possible to use go-git to
detect if a given repository is a submodule with some slight
modifications.


Is there a nice method for pure Go to check that the path given points to a git repository that is not a submodule?

To check whether it's being used as a submodule in any of the usual ways, in command-line Git,
path=$PWD bash <<\EOD
IFS=$'\n'
nope() { echo "$@"; exit; }
if ! toplevel=`git -C $path rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>&-`
then nope "$path is not in any repo work tree I can find"; fi
if ! up=`git -C $toplevel/.. rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>&-`
then nope "$path does not appear to be in a work tree used as a submodule"; fi
if ! index=`git -C $up rev-parse :${toplevel#$up/}` 
then nope "$path is in a nested work tree but its containing checkout is not using it"; fi
if [[ $(git -C $up ls-files -s ${toplevel#$up/}) != 160000* ]]
then nope $path is not listed as a checked-out submodule in $up; fi
echo $up is tracking ${toplevel#$up/} as a submodule.
EOD


Sorry to write this, but I am not looking for a solution that uses the git CLI.
I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement this in pure, some say idiomatic, go (aka. golang)

Well, it's Git, can you not translate this?

If only there was a way to combine the two answers. The one in Go will give wrong answers but it's (I assume idiomatic) Go as requested, this one isn't in Go but at least it gives the right answer. I guess relative importance isn't really an issue here?

@jthill: The one in Go will give wrong answers - why?

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk The two most common cases: it'll show added worktrees as submodules. It'll miss newly-created submodules (created for the project, not cloned). There are more.
